# (When) is this matrix positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I have a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix (say, $M$) with $[i,j]$ element

\begin{equation}
M_{[i,j]} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} [p_i(z)-g(z)][p_j(z)-g(z)]~dz,
\end{equation}

where $p_i(\cdot), p_j(\cdot),$ and $g(\cdot)$ are continuous probability density functions (pdfs).

I suspect, but have so far been unable to prove, that $M$ is positive definite (provided that the pdfs $p_i$ are distinct, see below). One example in which pd'ness holds is as follows:

For $i=1,\ldots,n,$ let $p_i(z) = 1(i < z \le i+1),$ where $1(A)$ is the indicator function of the event $A$. Furthermore, let $g(z) = 1(0 < z \le 1).$ In this example,

$$M_{[i,j]} = \begin{cases} 2 & i = j \\ 1 & \text{else} \end{cases},$$ hence $M$ is  positive definite. Interestingly, if we modify the example so that two pdfs are identical (e.g. let $p_{n}(z) = p_{n-1}(z)$, and leave the rest unchanged), we get 
$$M_{[i,j]} = \begin{cases} 2 & (i = j) \cup (i=n-1,j=n) \cup (i=n,j=n-1) \\ 1 & \text{else} \end{cases},$$
which is psd but not pd.

Is anybody aware of a more elegant/general approach to tackle this? Is it possible that the matrix belongs to a more general class which has been studied before? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Absent some good theorem to hit it with, I always start things like this by looking at some simple cases.  One would be where your matrix is 2x2.  You might pick $p_1,  p_2$ and g specifically just to get a handle on what is going on. Keep them as simple as possible.  I think the basic definition is the only way to go here -- i.e. multiply $x^TMx$ and see if it is positive for any x. If not, why not?  If so, what about the p's and g caused that. Can you find p's and g to construct a diagonal matrix with all positive entries?  That may give you a clue also.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'll edit the post to include a simple example. I was/am hoping that the matrix belongs to a class of matrices which is known to be positive definite.

Comment: Well, at least it is symmetric.  I do think you will have to say something more about the p's and the g. If you can weight them so that the diagonal elements are large (positive) and the off-diagonal elements small, that would help.  Your examples are interesting, but I think too simple to throw much light on this.

Comment: I think (?!) I got it: Define the $n \times 1$ vector $\tilde p(z) = \begin{bmatrix} p_1(z)-g(z) & \ldots & p_n(z)-g(z) \end{bmatrix}'$. Then we can write $$M = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde p(z) \tilde p(z)' dz.$$

Comment: This construction (integrating a matrix with respect to a scalar) seems nonstandard, but I cannot see why it should be wrong. For a fixed, real $n \times 1$ vector $b$ we then have \begin{eqnarray} b'Mb &=& \int_{\mathbb{R}} b'\tilde p(z) \tilde p(z)'b~dz \\ &=& \int_{\mathbb{R}} (s(z))^2~dz \ge 0,\end{eqnarray} where $s(z) = b'\tilde p(z).$ $M$ is thus strictly pd unless two rows of $\tilde p(z)$ are linearly dependent $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}.$ Since the $p_i$'s are pdfs (i.e., positive & integrate to one), this should only happen if there are some $i,j$ s.t. $p_i(z) = p_j(z)~\forall~z$.

Comment: I'm not quite following what is $\bar{p}(z)$ and what is $\bar{p}$(z)'

Comment: These are defined in the comment above my last one (I split the post in two comments to have enough characters...I should have written an answer instead :)).

Comment: okay I understand the $ \bar p(z)$.  But is that a dot product under the integral sign?  This would give you a single function which is the sum of $(p_i -g)^2$.  I don't see why that is your matrix.  I think you have a good idea with your p's, and you know where you are trying to go, but I'm not quite convinced you have nailed it.

Comment: $\tilde p(z)$ is of dimension $n \times 1$, and its transpose $\tilde p(z)'$ is $1 \times n$. The term under the integral for M is thus the outer product of $\tilde p(z)$, which is $n \times n$. The $[i,j]$ element of this outer product should be $(p_i(z)-g(z)) (p_j(z)-g(z)),$ as in the original definition of the matrix.

Comment: Didn't see that is was meant as an outer product. Based on your original definition of $M_{ij}$ the integral would be an element by element integration, so integration wrt a scalar makes perfect sense.  But can you explain where you got your $s^2$?  It isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Glad to hear you agree with the integral. The $s(z)$ is defined as $s(z) = b'\tilde p(z),$ where $b$ is the $n \times 1$ vector which appears in the quadratic form $b'Mb$. Note that since $b'\tilde p(z)$ and $\tilde p(z)'b$ are both scalars (i.e. of dimension $1 \times 1$), we have that $b'\tilde p(z) = \tilde p(z)'b = s(z)^2.$

Comment: What worries me is that this looks like an argument that any symmetric matrix is positive definite.  So either I've misunderstood something, or there is something not right in the argument.

Comment: I cannot see why the argument should imply that any symmetric matrix is pd. What it does imply is the much weaker statement that any matrix _which can be written as the outer product of a vector_  is positive _semi_ definite. As far as I know, this weaker statement is true.

Comment: You may be right.  I'll think some more when time permits.  It sure is a nice argument.